# Count under some condition and group by user

Tags: mysql

```
user     price     time
Chan      300     2015-02-10
Chan      200     2015-02-10
Chan      100     2015-02-11
Chan      200     2015-02-12    
Chan      200     2015-02-12    
Chan      200     2015-02-12    
Chan      400     2015-02-13
Phoebe    300     2015-02-10
....
```

I want to select a period like 2015-02-10 to 2015-02-16, if user pay equal or over to 500 each day will be count one, take `chan` for example, he spent 500 in 02-10, 600 in 02-12, therefore the count result is 2, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I used `CASE` statement to determine the price which is greater or equal to 500 and count it as one. Then I `SUM` it to get the total. Try my query below:

```
SELECT 
      time,
      user, 
      COUNT(price)CountResult
FROM YourTable
WHERE price>=500 AND time BETWEEN 2015-02-10 AND 2015-02-16 
GROUP BY user,time
```

Comment: It's not work, I need to sum by each day as one count

Comment: SELECT
    `user`,
    COUNT(`price`)
FROM (
        SELECT `user`, SUM(`price`) `price` FROM `tests` GROUP BY DATE(`date`), `user` HAVING SUM(`price`) >= 500
     ) `t`
GROUP BY `user`

I figure it out

Comment: It's totally different, I need to sum by each day